Trouble connecting deployed GitHub Pages site with Squarespace custom domain
I'm new to this world and don't have much experience with deploying.
I recently deployed a React site via GitHub Pages, and it's working perfectly (I'm utilizing multiple routes on this site as well). But when I go to connect it to my new Squarespace custom domain, I'm running into errors on both platforms.
Here's some more detail into the steps I'm following and errors I'm running into:
1. Get GitHub Pages URL: First, ensure that your GitHub Pages site is up and running. You should have a URL like https://yourusername.github.io/repository-name.
My GitHub Pages site is up and running and my URL is in this format: https://{GitHubname}.github.io/{repo-name}/
2. Custom Domain Settings in GitHub: In your GitHub repository settings, find the section for custom domains. Add your domain there (e.g., www.yourdomain.com). GitHub will provide you with instructions and possibly some DNS records to add to your domain's DNS settings.
When I add the custom Squarespace domain into this section on GitHub, I get the following error:
{domainename} is improperly configured
Domain does not resolve to the GitHub Pages server. For more information, see documentation (NotServedByPagesError)

3. Update DNS Settings in Squarespace:
Log in to your Squarespace account.
Go to the Domains section.
Find your domain and click on it.
Look for DNS settings or Advanced settings. You might need to navigate a bit depending on Squarespace's interface.
Add the DNS records provided by GitHub. Usually, this includes adding a CNAME record for your subdomain (if you're using www) pointing to your GitHub Pages URL.
When adding www and CNAME to Squarespace as {GitHubname}.github.io/{repo-name}/, I get the following error:
Enter valid alias data

Two other things of note (if helpful):

I added gh-pages to my devDep and deployment scripts within my project and I'm also deploying from my gh-pages branch in GitHub Pages.
I have multiple routes within this React site (/team, /contact, etc), and I'd like to ensure these routes are included within the Squarespace domain.

Any advice, troubleshooting steps, or additional documentation that could help me would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Have you followed all the steps listed in CRA's deployment docs? Does Squarespace have any additional steps and/or requirements you need to setup/configure?

Hi @DrewReese, I have followed those deployment docs steps and also reached out to Squarespace support. Apparently they don't support forward slashes for their CNAME settings? But this still doesn't help in this particular scenario.
